# Keeping ratio of bitmap

Tags: android, android-imageview

I change imageview source with bitmap in code but it does not keep ratio of it. It uses dimensions of the old image.

I set bitmap by;

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It stretches bitmap to fit dimensions of old image resource. I want to keep bitmap ratio.

Comment: use setScaleType to CENTER_CROP

Comment: CENTER_INSIDE is perfect   to maintain Bitmap Aspect Ratio in Imageview  Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the imageView ScaleTypes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

> CENTER    Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.
>
> CENTER_CROP   Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).
>
> CENTER_INSIDE     Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).
>
> FIT_CENTER    Scale the image using CENTER.
>
> FIT_END   Scale the image using END.
>
> FIT_START     Scale the image using START.
>
> FIT_XY    Scale the image using FILL.
>
> MATRIX    Scale using the image matrix when drawing.

You want something like CENTER_CROP or CENTER_INSIDE

Comment: I tried center_crop and center_inside but height does not change. Height is wrap_content but still uses old image resource height. Image width is match_parent by the way